# spring.profiles.active ist not set to the profile name specified on the command line for the maven build

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and have the following issue:

I use a standard spring boot project created with Spring Initializr.
I have setup maven resource filtering by specifying the following in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
...
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```

In the application.properties i have specified the following:

`spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@`

And I have defined the following profiles in the pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-dev-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
      <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-test-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
      <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-prod-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The standard test class is defined as:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class DocumentComposerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Now when I run the following maven command:

`mvn clean package -Ptest`

Then the following artifact is build:

`app-test-1.0.0.war`

But in the application.properties file there is the following:

`spring.profiles.active=dev`

So maven is correctly building the artifact with the profile "test" given on the command line.
But the resource filtering is putting the value from the "dev" profile as spring.profiles.active in the application.properties file.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve a maven build where the spring.profiles.active will be correctly replaced in the application-properties with the "test" value specified in the test profile?

Comment: You should simply put a file `application-dev.properties` in your `src/test/resources` folder which will be used during the test and there is no need to do strange things with profiles etc. related to Spring Boot. You can also use yml files which allows you to integrate all profiles into a single file...only separation between production and test.

Comment: I actually have a `application-dev.properties` and a `application-test.properties` and also a `application-prod.properties`. I just want to do a maven build with profile test so that i get this profile name in the application.properties replaced and it will be used when I deploy the war in the application server. But for the unit tests I want to use a different profile. This is not a strange thing but rather a basic thing.

Comment: If you like to have an `application.properties` for your test put that into `src/test/resources`. Furthermore the other setup can simply be done by giving the spring profile at start...and don't use maven profiles etc. I suppose you are using `war` file cause you will deploying it into a Tomcat etc. which means to configure the appropriate profile of spring boot there. Apart from that usually a microservice contains no configuration at all. It will get it from outside but the other thing is if such infrastructure does not exist the war/jar file contains all profiles...

Answer (score 0):

To sum up you tried specifying the *active profile* by these steps:

1. included a **default profile** by using `<activeByDefault>` tag (in your case the `dev` profile)
2. set an **additional** active profile by using option `-P` when running maven (in your case the `test` profile)

Seems like both profiles got activated, whereby:

1. profile `test` was used for naming the built artifact
2. profile `dev` was used as value for property `spring.profiles.active`.

Please run `mvn help:active-profiles` as described in [Maven: The Complete Reference - 5.4. Listing Active Profiles](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-listing-active-profiles.html) to list current active profiles.

One trick is to **avoid `<activeByDefault>`**, and instead activate the profile by passing **only the `-P` option** when running maven.

Comment: This command shows me that only the test profile is active when I use: `mvn help:active-profiles clean package -Ptest`

Comment: @MarcusWyremblewski Did you remove `<activation>` element from POM profiles and tried then?

Comment: when i remove the activation then i have the following in the `application.properties`: `spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.  However, I noticed that closing my development IDE and executing the maven command manually the issue disappeared.
Eventually I traced it to the Java:AutoBuild setting in my Visual Studio Code IDE. Disabling the setting resolved the issue.
Eclipse BTW suffers from the same problem.